# Multi currency apex test method

Tags: apex, multi-currency

I have a class that gets an object that has a Currency field called `Amount__c`.

I am updating all my queries to work for a multi-currency org. So my query now becomes:

```sql
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Amount__c, 
    convertCurrency(Amount__c) Converted___Amount__c 
FROM Revenue__c 
WHERE xyz
```

In my test class, I need to check if that object is getting the converted currency alias, but I can't use `.get` cos it tells me that field doesn't exist on the `Revenue__c` object. Can anyone tell me how I check if the alias is on the object returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "__c" from your alias:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Amount__c, 
    convertCurrency(Amount__c) ConvertedAmount 
FROM Revenue__c 
WHERE xyz
```

then you can use .get('ConvertedAmount')

Comment: Doesnt work. USed a different field than above (Annual_Revenue__c). I get an error:  Invalid field ConvertedAnnualRevenue for Revenue__c

Comment: Not sure what you're doing differently, this is working for me: `list<Opportunity> lo = [SELECT 
          Id, 
          Amount, 
          convertCurrency(Amount) cA 
                            FROM Opportunity];
system.debug(lo[0].get('cA'));`

Comment: Yep, it appears the problem was caused by an issue earlier in my method. Thanks lads.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check the field API name correctly. For your reference, all below work correctly:

**SOQL 1:**

```
for(Account acc: [SELECT Id, 
                  Name,
                  convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue)
                  FROM Account limit 10
                 ]) 
{
    System.debug('AnnualRevenue => '+acc.get('AnnualRevenue'));    
}
```

**SOQL 2:**

```
for(Account acc: [SELECT Id, 
                  Name, AnnualRevenue,
                  convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue) an__Rev
                  FROM Account limit 10
                 ]) 
{
    System.debug('an__Rev => '+acc.get('an__Rev'));    
}
```

**SOQL 3:**

```
for(Account acc: [SELECT Id, 
                  Name, AnnualRevenue,
                  convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue) an__Rev__c
                  FROM Account limit 10
                 ]) 
{
    System.debug('an__Rev__c => '+acc.get('an__Rev__c'));    
}
```